# array to string error in multiple ulpoad files

Tags: php, html, pdo

I Have A form that's have two inputs file one regular and the second is multiple and in one if statment i get them both but in the part

```
if (!empty($_FILES['logo']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['materials']['name']))
```

the

```
     $_FILES['materials']
```

is the multiple

i have tried to

```
   json_encode()
```

the

```
   $_FILES['materials']
```

but isn't work, its not pass the first if to the

```
  is_uploaded_file()
```

/*php*/

```
 define('IMG_MAX_SIZE', 1024 * 1024 * 5);
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $ex = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp'];

if (!empty($_FILES['logo']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['materials']['name']) 
 ) {
    $matToStr = json_encode($_FILES['materials']);

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'])  &&  
    is_uploaded_file($matToStr)) {
    echo "in";
        if ($_FILES['logo']['error'] == 0 && $_FILES['logo']['size'] <= 
    IMG_MAX_SIZE  && $_FILES['materials']['error'] == 0 && 
     $_FILES['materials']['size'] <= IMG_MAX_SIZE) {
    echo "in2";
            $logoInfo = pathinfo($_FILES['logo']['name']);
            $materialsInfo = pathinfo($_FILES['materials']['name']);

            if (in_array(strtolower($logoInfo['extension']), $ex)  && in_array(strtolower($materialsInfo['extension']), $ex)) {

                $logo = date('Y.m.d.H.i.s') . '-' . $_FILES['logo']['name'];
                $materials = date('Y.m.d.H.i.s') . '-' . $_FILES['materials']['name'];

                $_SESSION['logo'] = $logo;
                $_SESSION['materials'] = $materials;

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $logo);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['materials']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $materials);

                $pdo = DB();
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO client_form_7 (client_id, logo, materials, websites) VALUES (:client_id, :logo, :materials, :websites)");
                $stmt->bindParam("client_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam("logo", $logo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam("materials", $materials, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam("websites", $websites, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();

                if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                    header('location: client-form-7.php?sm=תמונת הפרופיל עודכנה');
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

/*html*/

```
 <form action="" method="post" class="col s12" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h4>7.  קבצים וחומרים</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="file-field input-field col s6">
        <p>לוגו</p>
        <div class="btn">
          <span>בחר קובץ</span>
          <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
          <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="file-field input-field col s6">
        <p>צילומים וחומרים שעלולים להיות רלוונטי</p>
        <div class="btn">
          <span>בחר קובץ</span>
          <input type="file" name="materials[]" id="materials" multiple>
        </div>
        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
          <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input type="text" name="websites" id="websites" value="<?=old('websites')?>">
        <label for="websites">אתרי אינטרנט שניתן למשוך משם חומרים</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
         <input type="submit" class="btn left" value="העלה קבצים" name="submit">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

i expected tha'ts upload the one regular file input
and the scond upload like array because i want to fetch it later

Comment: Your `materials` input is an "HTML array". Change from `name="materials[]"` to `name="materials"`.

Comment: ok this is now move the files to the folder, but its not insert to db, and its not trow me an error @Qirel